How to get Satellite data in flutter?
I need to retrive some satellite data (GPS/GLNSS etc) in a flutter android app.
What I need is to get SNR, signal strenght, and build a "costellation map" like in apps like GPS Test https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/2ZTVAQX_X5nnYpEpVYIStTnFPDLpjlELAT8mfzo1ZV3opecTEhmOCBzsCpHnulwYWpY=w2560-h1440-rw
I looked on flutter docs, but I did not found usefull info. Any idea?
